# Trying to understand PIC datasheet for the PIC 12F683

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I'm new at asking questions on this forum so please forgive me if my format needs to be cleaned up. I have a PIC 12F683 datasheet. I'm trying to understand how, for instance, ANSEL=0 to set I/O to digital is obtained from a datasheet.

I have searched the web for some clues, but all I seem to find is "it just is." That's not helping me. I just need a little help getting past the bridge between the datasheet information and the actual code that manipulates these ports. Page 39 of "Programming PICs in Basic and page 32 (4-2) of the datasheet makes no sense to me... I'm not the first to post this sort of question from what I have found, but they didn't provide specifics. I'm hoping what I have provided will be enough for one of you folks to see what my question is and help.

I can see on page 31 (4.1 of the datasheet) that the TRISIO register determines direction and it seems clear that applying a "1" to that register will make the corresponding GPIO pin an input and so forth. But when it comes to the ANSEL=0 I'm lost- can't seem to make sense of this. Can someone please throw me a bone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking this datasheet for the PIC12F683 (To ensure we're using the same version of datasheet):
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/41211d_.pdf

Section 4.0 "GPIO PORT" offers a complete description on how the IO port works. You should read this On the right hand side of the page it says:

"Note:
The ANSEL and CMCON0 registers must
be initialized to configure an analog
channel as a digital input. Pins configured
as analog inputs will read ‘
0
’."

This means if ANSEL and CMCON0 are not configured, any reads on a IO pin that doubles as analog input will always return 0.

Further down in that section at 4.2 you get the detailed description about the ANSEL register and it's bit mask on the next page:

```
Bits 0 to 3
ANS<3:0>: Analog Select bits
Analog select between analog or digital function on pins AN<3:0>, respectively.
1 = Analog input. Pin is assigned as analog input(1).
0 = Digital I/O. Pin is assigned to port or special function.
```

So, writing XXXX0000 to ANSEL makes all pins digital IO. XXXX0001 would make AN0 analog and the other 3 digital, and so on.

CMCOM0's bitmask is described under section 8.7

```
<snip>
111 = CIN pins are configured as I/O, COUT pin is configured as I/O, Comparator output disabled, Comparator off.
```

So you need to write XXXXX111 to CMCON0 to disable the comparator and free the pins for digital IO.

Comment: Thank you for responding- before I get more into the datasheet I am confused by the <3:0>. Forgive me for coming across stupid- the colon is throwing me. Part 4.1 shows, for instance, bit 5:4 TRISIO<5:4>. what is the colon referencing?

Comment: Most everything else you have indicated is beginning to make sense- thank you so very much- this is wonderful. I'm beginning to have that "clue." It's that colon separating numeric that is still throwing me though.

Comment: <x:y> is a bitrange from bit X to Y in the given register. So TRISIO<5:4> means bits 5 & 4 of TRISIO.

Comment: OK... that makes sense, but... oh boy here it comes... why not use the dash as in "bit 7-6" right above that statement on the same page (page 32)? then below, it states bit 2:0 TRISIO<2:0>- then in  the notes (2 and 3) just below it says TRISIO<5:4> always reads etc... then below that it says TRISIO<5> always reads etc. That's why I'm confused. What you say makes sense- the datasheet is confusing me on this point. The note is repeating TRISIO 5 in both statements but saying different things for the same register. Can you shed some further clarification???

Comment: BTW- thanks to you I understand now why I wasn't getting any output on GPIO 3 as it is clearly defined as an input- not capable of it being an output. Was completely pulling my hair out.

Comment: TRISIO<5:4> controls the input/output direction of GPIO pins 5 and 4. If you read trough section 4.0- GPIO port completely you will learn that pins 5 and 4 can also be used for an external oscillator. that's why the note says "TRISIO<5:4> always reads ‘
1
’ in XT, HS and LP OSC modes", which are external oscillator modes. Pin 3 can only be used as input, so "TRISIO<3> always reads ‘
1
’ because if you write 0 to it (to make it an output) it will get ignored and stay 1.

Comment: I'm going to digest all your great information. I only see pins 2 and 3 as clock input pins- I'm unsure where you are getting pins 5 and 6 for external clock- I see pin 5 as GPIO2 and 6 as GPIO1. Are you referring to the timer functions?

Comment: 4.2.5.5 " The GP4 pin
is configurable to function as one of the following" ...  etc

Comment: Please note that GPIO pin numbers and actual pins on the chip do not have the same number. For example GPIO5 is pin 2 on the chip. I think this is confusing you somewhat

Comment: Absolutely see it now. Thank you. I can't move your answer up as I'm new- I checked it though.